# Python kivy error: Errno2 no such file or directory

Tags: python, kivy

hi i have the following code in my main.py file

```
store = JsonStore(r'save/budgets/{}'.format(budgetName))
store.put('budget', items= ['soap','drinks'], total=10)
```

Where "budgetName" is gotten from a textinput entry.
"save" is a folder in the same directory as my main.py, 
and "budgets" is a folder found in the "save" directory,
the plan is to create the .json file in the budgets directory.
This used to work when i tested on kivy launcher on my android phone. But once i created an apk,
it crashes the program with the error exception

```
Errno 2: No such file or directory
```

please how do i fix this

Comment: Are you sure that the `save/budgets` folder exists in the APK?

Comment: I dont know. I created the budget folder and placed it in the save directory, which is a package coz it contains an __init__.py file. So as far as I know the folder save/budget did exist. But after making the apk I don't know how to confirm if it's there.

Comment: Hi finally got it based on your suspicion. The folder 'save' was included in the apk but the budgets folder wasn't, hence the error. So I added a code to create the folder. Thanks for the help